# Simplified and traditional Chinese characters in LaTeX

Tags: chinese

I have limited experience writing Chinese characters in LaTeX. I am currently using the package CJKutf8. With the command `\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi} \end{CJK*}` I can print traditional Chinese characters, and with the command `\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn} \end{CJK}` I can print simplified Chinese characters. But I have a document where some characters are simplified and some are traditional. Is there a way to print both, without having to switch between the two commands a character at a time?

Comment: You can use `xeCJK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build with `xelatex`. You can also change the font. And setting fallback font is also supporting. I suggest you read the doc of `xeCJK`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
测试简体
測試繁體
\end{document}
```

[image]